# deploy remote event receiver with Azure IIS

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, remote-event-receiver, azure-service-bus

I am trying to use Remote Event Receiver with a SharePoint Custom List and it is not deploying.  When I debug with Visual Studio, it works.  When I deploy it as an app, it fails deploying with the below error:

> The remote event receiver callout failed.
>
> Details: The server was unable to process the request due to an
>   internal error. For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults  (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send
>   the exception information back to the client, or turn on  tracing as
>   per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the
>   server trace logs.

Can someone help me or tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am assuming that I have not setup my connection with Azure correctly.